# jQuery locate closest value in a table and scroll to its row

Tags: jquery, filter, html-table, scrolltop

I have a table loaded with ajax looking:

```
   <div id="Dprg">
    <table>
        <tr><td ord="1">06:00</td><td>Event 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td ord="2">06:30</td><td>Event 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td ord="3">06:45</td><td>Event 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td ord="4">07:00</td><td>Event 4</td></tr>
        <tr><td ord="5">07:30</td><td>Event 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td ord="6">08:25</td><td>Event 6</td></tr>
        <tr><td ord="7">08:45</td><td>Event 7</td></tr>
        <tr><td ord="8">09:10</td><td>Event 8</td></tr>
                    ....etc...
        <tr><td ord="58">00:30</td><td>Event 58</td></tr>        
    </table>
  </div>
```

This table is viewed in a 10% (window-size) height div. I want that after loading a table in this div it scrolls to the actual running event: Get the actual time and compare it to the first  and scroll to it. 
Here is my Jquery function for scrolling just after ajax file loading, It runs ok (not even accurate) for the first loaded file but if I load another program into that div ..It scrolls wrong:

```
   function scrollinfo(){
    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + (dt.getMinutes()<10?'0':'')+ dt.getMinutes();  
    $('#Dprg tr').each(function() {
    var myst = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();   
    if (myst >= time){$('#Dprg').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top-($('#Dprg').height()/2)}, 1000 );return false;}
    }); 
    }
```

Am so grateful for any help.

Comment: Any idea?.. looks not that complicated or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as nobody answered and in case of somebody else has a similar problem here the solution: After loading data with ajax I had to re-scroll the div to the top (scroll to 0) which will be the initial step. Than I had to better consider the time (add '0' if <10) for minutes and hours. Finally a 3rd column which will hold the ending time of each event (3 columns table instead of 2). That'S it!
here is the final function:

```
function scrollinfo(){
$('#Dprg').scrollTop(0); //very important 
var dt = new Date();
var time = (dt.getHours()<10?'0':'')+(dt.getHours()+ ":" + 
 (dt.getMinutes()<10?'0':'')+ dt.getMinutes();

$('Table tr').each(function() {
var beg = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html(); 
var fin = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html(); 
if (beg <=time && time <=fin){  
    $('#Dprg').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top}, 1000 );
    return false;
    }       
    }); 
}
```

And to finalize the idea I added an onmouseleave="scrollinfo();" to the table that after manually scrolling it comes back to the right row again (actual running event).. and that runs smooth!
Thank you stackoverflow big family and take care all :-) !.